# Set UIImage height based on a ratio of the width using Autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistoryboard

I am trying to figure out how to set the height of a UIimage on the storyboard based on the width? I need it to be a ratio based on the width. So the image is full width.

Currently I am using the universal storyboard and want the image to be 3:4 so the height needs to be 33% greater than the width.

What I don't understand is the width is 600 on the universal storyboard so how do I then get the ratio of the height being 33% greater than the width?

I can't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add a`UIImageView` to the Storyboard and manually set it to the ratio you want, e.g. 300x400px, you can then click the pin button on the bottom right (shown below) and check the box that says "aspect ratio". That will add a constraint to always keep your view the same aspect ratio, even as you change the width.

[image]

Comment: Ok that makes sense but I want the image to be full width so would need to be 600 width no?

Comment: Depending on your device, yes. The important thing for the aspect ratio is that you set it at *some* 3:4 ratio. You can then add a width constraint that will fix it as wide or narrow as you want, and the height will follow according to the ratio